# Ajax Query using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am currently developing a website and was using strictly PHP, after a few hours of development I am noticing I really need to perform AJAX queries. However I am using CI and slightly confused on how I call Ajax queries - especially to a controllers method. I am looking to post data using the query,I have found the following using Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

but if I had a controller called main and method called postBack() - how would I pass postback() the data?

Could anyone point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated - apologies if this is extremely simple to say I am a newbie is an understatement.

Comment: How would you pass `postback()` the data if you were just submitting a form?

Comment: I guess I would set the URL to the URL to in my case localhost/main/postback

however I have no idea what to include in the data, success or dataType fields?

Comment: They are [documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in the jQuery documentation

Comment: how would I send a PHP variable using the ajax query?

Comment: You output it as you would with any other PHP content you want to send to the browser (e.g. with `echo`).

Comment: so my data field would be:
data: <?php echo $variable?>;

Comment: This question has been asked/answered a thousand times over, try the search feature.

Comment: The search feature of this site is not helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Codeingiter/Jquery function pair that I wrote not long ago:

Javascript:

```
var BASE_URL = <?php echo base_url(); ?>
var stuff = "";

 $('div.get_this').each(function(){
    if(stuff ){
        stuff = stuff + '-';
    }
    stuff = stuff + $(this).html();
});

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: BASE_URL+"gate",
  data: {'data':stuff},
  success: function(data){
    ...
  });
});
```

Codeigniter Controller:

```
class Gate extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){

        if(isset($_POST['data'])){

            $data = explode('-', $_POST['data']);
```

Comment: I'm slighty confused what did you assign the stuff variable?

Comment: I add to my example.  This example is a bit silly, but it shows how you can build your 'stuff' string

Answer (score 0):

In Ci u will use Ajax the for the URL part u will add the controller function name example var URL="HOME SITE URL"+"main/post Back"; //here main is controller and post Back is function that u want to call like below. $Ajax({ type: "POST",URL: URL,data: {star: 3},success: success,data Type: data Type }); and after that in post Back function in controller we used function post Back() { $variable1 = $_POST["star"]; //or $_GET["star"]
or $this->input->post('star');
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass extends MyController {

    function postBack(){
        //dosomething with post data
        $postdata = $this->input->post();
        $somearray = filter_something($postdata);
        //this is where you return the output to jQuery. you output a string in JSON format 
        echo json_encode($some_array);
    }

}
```